# Looping through two arrays to check if values match, if not change value

Tags: vba, excel

Question updated to make it clear what I am asking and updated the code based on help from the comments.

I have two tables, each with a persons ID, Name, Team and Manager.

Table 1 has the data held previously and Table 2 has the live data which will be updating daily.

I have now created the arrays which loop successfully storing the data from both tables and changes the values in the VBA watch window to match. The issue is during the output I get type data mismatch.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Function UpdateReports(rName, srcSheet)

  Dim Counter As Long
  Dim rr As Long
  Dim zz As Long
  Dim x As Long

  Dim aPID() As String
  Dim aName() As String
  Dim aTeam() As String
  Dim aOps() As String
  Dim aRole() As String


  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  rPath = "%systemdrive%\users\%username%\Desktop\"
  Creator = rPath & "Test Workbook.xlsm"
  RepDest = rPath & rName & ".xlsx"
  Set sWbk = Nothing
  Set sWbk = Workbooks.Open(RepDest, True, True)

  'Store tList into Array
  Workbooks(Creator).Worksheets("tList").Visible = True
  Workbooks(Creator).Worksheets("tList").Activate
  Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
  zz = Selection.Rows.Count - 1
  rr = 1
  x = 0

  Do Until rr > zz ' repeat until end of Staff
    rr = rr + 1
    x = x + 1
    ReDim Preserve aID(1 To x) As String
    ReDim Preserve aName(1 To x) As String
    ReDim Preserve aTeam(1 To x) As String
    ReDim Preserve aManager(1 To x) As String


    aID(x) = Int(Cells(rr, 1).Value) ' Store ID
    aName(x) = Cells(rr, 2).Value ' Store Name
    aTeam(x) = Cells(rr, 3).Value ' Store Team
    aManager(x) = Cells(rr, 6).Value ' Store Manager

  Loop

'Compare tList to data sheet in report
  Workbooks(RepDest).Worksheets(srcSheet).Activate
  Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
  XY = Selection.Rows.Count
  For y = 3 To XY
    bID = Cells(y, 1).Value
    bName = Cells(y, 2).Value
    bTeam = Cells(y, 3).Value
    bManager = Cells(y, 4).Value
    For Z = 1 To zz
      If bID = aID(Z) Then
        bName = aName(Z)
        bTeam = aTeam(Z)
        bManager = aManager(Z)
      End If
    Next z
  Next y


'  Dim vArray As Variant
'    ReDim vArray(LR)
'    For x = 8 To LR
'      vArray(x) = Cells(x, 3).Value
'    Next x
'    Worksheets("Breaks Overuse").Activate
'    Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Select
'    XY = Selection.Rows.Count
'    For y = 2 To XY
'      PID = Cells(y, 2).Value
'      For Z = 8 To LR
'        If ID = vArray(Z) Then
'          Rows(y).Delete
'          y = y - 1
'          XY = XY - 1
'        End If
'      Next Z
'    Next y

  Sheets(srcSheet).Select
  Counter = 0
  yy = 1
  With Sheets(srcSheet).Range("A1")
    For Counter = 1 To x
        .Offset([yy], [0]).Value = Format(bID(Counter), "0") 'This is where I get type mismatch, the value for bID is <type mismatch> but in the part above this the value is the ID number 123456
        .Offset([yy], [1]).Value = Format(bName(Counter), "@")
        .Offset([yy], [2]).Value = Format(bTeam(Counter), "@")
        .Offset([yy], [3]).Value = Format(bManager(Counter), "@")

        yy = yy + 1
    Next
  End With
  Set sWbk = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: And the question is...? If what you want is a code review, I'd suggest posting this to [the appropriate SE site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You don't want to redim arrays in a loop. It repeatedly generates copies I believe. Declare dynamic arrays, oversize them at the start, use counter variables in the loop and redim your arrays using the counters at the end.

Comment: Please note that `Dim Counter, rr, zz, x As Long` will define `x As Long` but all others are of type `Variant`. You need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim Counter As Long, rr As Long, zz As Long, x As Long` otherwise VBA will automatically default them to `Variant`.

Comment: Hi @Inarion my question is if what I am doing makes sense or if there is a better way to do it, and if it is correct then am I doing the correct thing during my For Loops and the output toward the bottom? Mainly the second half of the code is where I am lost. Sorry this wasn't clear in the above.

Comment: Is your code producing the expected result?

Comment: How about a dictionary with ID as key and an array of the other values as the item? There's an `.Exists()` method to check for the ID. You'd just have to remember to add a new ID to both the dictionary and the table.

Comment: @QHarr no, I am getting a compile error: Can't assign to read-only property. It is highlighting the Function line in yellow but highlighting the text of `Creator = rPath & "Test Workbook.xlsm"`

Comment: I don't know but there should be a path separator in there ("\") before the workbook part. I don't think the error is really that line if Creater is  a local string variable.

Comment: @Doog_Dooger Can you please add the line where `Creator` is declared to your question. Right now it's hard to tell what's going on. (Never mind. It is a read-only property of a number of Excel objects...)

Comment: @QHarr I did have it in my code, just missed it on this page, I've edited the question now to show the "\", Inarion thank you, I totally forgot to declare it, rookie mistake haha. My bad. Going through the rest of my code now to see what is happening so I can clarify my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign a value to a property `Creator` that is **read-only**. (It also carries an implicit reference to the `Application` object, I believe. So you're actually using `Application.Creator`.)

I'm not sure what your intention in using this property is. Have you checked its value? According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-creator-property-excel), it is a constant value. As far as I understand it, when the document was created in a Mac environment, the value might be different. In any case, it doesn't seem very useful for me to name a workbook after it.

As far as building a new workbook name goes, you should really use a new variable for that. Application/document properties (even if writable) are not the place to store runtime information of your script.

---

As @QHarr already mentioned in the comments, you will *never* want to `ReDim` your array within a loop (unless you can help it, but be aware: this smells...).
In your case, it is definitely not necessary to do so:

```
zz = Selection.Rows.Count - 1
rr = 1
x = 0
Do Until rr > zz ' repeat until end of Staff
    rr = rr + 1
    x = x + 1
    ReDim Preserve aID(1 To x) As String
    ReDim Preserve aName(1 To x) As String
    ReDim Preserve aTeam(1 To x) As String
    ReDim Preserve aManager(1 To x) As String

    ' assignments removed for brevity
Loop
```

When the loop starts, the exit condition is already known (you probably should also rewrite this loop as a `For ... Next` loop). The value `zz` is known and constant during the loop. The starting value for `rr` is known, as is the increment. So from the start you know what the value of `rr` will be at the end. In consequence you also know what `x` will be at the end and thus what your final size for the arrays needs to be.

The loop runs from `rr = 2` (as it starts with `r = 1` and then immediately increments it by 1) to `rr = zz` (as it stops for `rr > zz`) with `Step 1`. As `x` is incremented at the same time, with the same increment, but starts at 0 instead of 1, the final value for x will be `x = zz - 1`. With that knowledge we can then refactor to:

```
zz = Selection.Rows.Count - 1
' First dimension arrays outside of the loop
Dim xMax as Long
xMax = zz - 1
ReDim Preserve aID(1 To xMax) As String
ReDim Preserve aName(1 To xMax) As String
ReDim Preserve aTeam(1 To xMax) As String
ReDim Preserve aManager(1 To xMax) As String
' Proceed with filling the arrays in a For ... Next loop
' the index x has been replaced by rr-1
For rr = 2 to zz
    aID(rr-1) = Int(Cells(rr, 1).Value) ' Store ID
    aName(rr-1) = Cells(rr, 2).Value ' Store Name
    aTeam(rr-1) = Cells(rr, 3).Value ' Store Team
    aManager(rr-1) = Cells(rr, 6).Value ' Store Manager
Next rr
```

---

Regarding your type mismatch error: I can't tell why it happens as you haven't shown us the declarations for all your `b` variables. And your usage of those variables is inconsistent. At first you seem to be using them as scalars in `bID = Cells(y, 1).Value` and `If bID = aID(Z) Then`, but later on you do `Format(bID(Counter), "0")`, where it's used as an array. You are not only confusing others with this, but also your future self, when you have to look at these lines in a month's time.

Generally: Did you put `Option Explicit` somewhere at the top of your code module? If not, please do so, *asap*. I have a feeling this might solve most of your problems. (And if it's not there, please go to the VBE options and enable `Require variable declaration` on the first page. This will automatically write `Option Explicit` in every module you create from then on.)

Comment: Perfect thanks @Inarion I hadn't declared it correctly and this caused the error, I have gotten past this part now thanks to your help. I am now at the part where my original question lay, I have built my arrays and they are accepting the values correctly, however when I am trying to output the correct values then it is giving me a type mismatch error, I have edited my code to highlight where this happens.

Comment: That's great, thanks for this. You were totally correct in that I tried to call them as an array but hadn't set it up correctly as an array during my declarations and missed out the array letter completely at the end. I will rewrite as you have suggested and not ReDim as you mentioned. Thank you so much for your help.